# How to validate checkbuttons & radiobuttons

Tags: php, validation, checkbox, radio-button

I have all ready succeded with validating number, email and message and so on.

My problem now is how do I validate radio/check btn.

Here is how i validate etc Message:

```
// Validates msg

if (!isset($_POST[$field]) || empty($_POST['message'])) {
    $error_msg .= " ";  
    $fieldStatusMessage = 'style="border:1px solid #F00"';
}
else {
    $fieldStatusEmail = '';
}
```

Would be helpful if someone could explain or show me. I thinks its really close to what im doing now ?

Comment: There are several ways, it depends on the value of your check and radio buttons as you could have them as strings or numbers. Also your example only validates that the message is not empty... nothing else. Depending on what it's for malicious code could be included.

Comment: Yeah i know , im just after to check "if not empty" validation but instead of message on buttons/radio btns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below

**Example 1**

PHP

```
<?php
  if($_Post[]) {
        if($_POST['list'] == -1)
                echo 'Please select one on the List';
         else {
                ............
         }
}
?>
```

HTML

```
<form method="post">
 <select name="list">
         <option value="-1">Select One</option>
         <option value="1">One</option>
         <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

**Example 2**

HTML

```
<form name="frm1" action="action.php" method="post">
    Active ? 
    <input type="radio" name="myrdo" value="Y" /> Yes
    <input type="radio" name="myrdo" value="N" /> No
    <br />
    Education:
    <input type="checkbox" name="mychk" value="G" /> Graduate
    <br />
    Country:
    <select name="country">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
        <option value="1">USA</option>
        <option value="2">UK</option>
        <option value="3">Canada</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit Form" />
</form>
```

PHP

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){ 
    $error_msg = array(); 
    if(!isset($_POST['myrdo'])){ 
        $error_msg[] = "No radio buttons were checked."; 
    } 
    if(!isset($_POST['mychk'])){ 
        $error_msg[] = "Graguate was checked"; 
    } 
    if(!isset($_POST['country'])){ 
        $error_msg[] = "No country as selected."; 
    } 

    if(isset($error_msg) && count($error_msg) == 0){ 
        // do some form processing 
    } 
    else{ 
        // redirect to the form again. 
    } 
}
```

[***Read more***](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php4p10.html)

Answer (score 1):

For a checkbox if the user checked it you will have a $_POST['checkboxName'] equal to "on". If the user unchecked it, $_POST['checkboxName'] won't exist.

For a radio button you will have a $_POST['radioName'] equal to value selected (html attribut value)

Comment: Sounds promising , would you explain little more ?

Answer (score 0):

```
// if not checked consider FALSE
$checkbox = (empty($_POST['checkbox_name'])) ? FALSE : TRUE;

// if not selected consider FALSE otherwise use value from HTML.
$radio = (empty($_POST['radio_name'])) ? FALSE : $_POST['radio_name'];
```